# Cant render partialViews on a View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

im trying to render different partial views depending on the click of a sidebar, when i click on 1 of the elements in the sidebar it calls the jquery that has a url.action that should redirect to a controller and the specific controller should return a view, the thing is that it dont find the controller, i have the action inside the accountcontroller, and its called _InformacaoBasica

**Here is what i did**

**View with sidebar links**

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:15px">
<div class="col-md-2" style="border-right:1px solid gray;">
    <div class="row caixaUser" id="linkInfo" style="margin-top:25px;padding:5px;">
        <a href="#" class="linkUser"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user black"></span> Informação básica</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row caixaUser" style="margin-top:25px;padding:5px;">
        <a href="#" class="linkUser" id="linkOutra"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open black"></span> Outras Informações</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row caixaUser" style="margin-top:25px;padding:5px;">
        <a href="#" class="linkUser" id="linkSegu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock black"></span> Segurança</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row caixaUser"  style="margin-top:25px;padding:5px;">
        <a href="#" class="linkUser" id="linkTag"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags black"></span> Tags</a>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    </div>
```

**My Jquery**

```
 $('#linkInfo').click(function () {
    $('.vistaParcial').load('@Url.Action("_InformacaoBasica", "Account")')
});
```

my controller

```
public ActionResult _InformacaoBasica()
{
    var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    ApplicationUser user = db.Users.Include(u => u.Tags).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(id));
    preencherTagUtilizador(user);
    var role = (from s in db.Roles where s.Id == user.TipoUtilizador select s.Name).First();

    EditarUtilizadorViewModel model = new EditarUtilizadorViewModel();
    model.Utilizador = user.Nome;
    model.Email = user.Email;

    return PartialView("~/Views/PartialViews/_InformacaoBasica",model);
}
```

Comment: Is that script in a external js file?

Comment: yes, but he finds the scipt, i get this error on console http://localhost:38058/Account/@Url.Action(%22_InformacaoBasica%22, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Razor code is not parsed in external files. In each link add `data-url="@@Url.Action(...)` and in the script use `$('.vistaParcial').load($(this).data('url'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot include razor directives (e.g. `@Url.Action`) in an external JS file.  You've either got to do this in inline code in the view, or you've got to work out the URL yourself and include this:

```
$('#linkInfo').click(function () {
    $('.vistaParcial').load('/Account/_InformacaoBasica')
});
```

If your site is not being hosted at the domain root then you'll have to account for this too.

Comment: well im the programer that like to know why things happen, can you explain it for me seems kinda confusing :S

Comment: Because, as far as MVC is concerned, js files are static files, like an image.  They are not "parsed" like cshtml files, they are sent to the client as-is.  Therefore if you have "@Url.Action" then you get "@Url.Action" literal, not the parsed action url.

Comment: now i get this, http://localhost:38058/Account/_InformacaoBasica Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)